# Convexity of the orthogonal Procrustes problem

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-analysis, orthogonal-matrices, procrustes-problem

Given two orthogonal matrices ${\bf{M}} \in {{\Bbb{R}}^{m \times n}}$ and ${\bf{N}} \in {{\Bbb{R}}^{m \times n}}$, there is an orthogonal transformation matrix ${\bf{T}} \in {{\Bbb{R}}^{n \times n}}$ which closely maps ${\bf{M}}$ and ${\bf{N}}$:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & {\left\| {{\bf{M}} - {\bf{NT}}} \right\|_F}\\ \text{subject to} & {{\bf{T}}^T}{\bf{T}} = {\bf{I}}\end{array}$$

Is this a convex optimization problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not convex because the feasible set (the set of matrices $T$ satisfying $T^TT = I$) is not a convex set.

For instance, $I$ and $-I$ are both orthogonal matrices, but their non-trivial convex combinations (that is, every $T = (1 - \theta) I + \theta(-I)$ with $\theta \in (0,1)$) fail to be orthogonal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am aware that there is a method to solve this problem for a unique answer through SVD. Does it mean that this method gives only a local minimum?

Comment: @ar_k Actually, the SVD method gives a global minimum.  Also the SVD method is not iterative (i.e. not a descent method), so there is no need to worry about getting "trapped" at a particular minimum.  It is well known that a unique solution exists if and only if the matrix $BA^T$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks! It is clear and useful.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you for your response. shouldn't we say the constraint $X^tX=I$ is not a `convex function` instead of being a `convex set`? More accurately, shouldn't we say it is not an affine function due to the fact that in convex problems the equality should just be an affine function.

Comment: @Media the constraint is an equation, not a function, so I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom YES :) my mistake about function. Please consider the latter part of my question. Shouldn't we say, it should be affine set?

Comment: @Media I don't understand your question

Comment: You've referred 
*It is not convex because the feasible set (the set of matrices T satisfying $T^TT=I$) is not a convex set*. I guess the last part should be **affine set** and not *convex set*. Because equality constraints should be affine.

Comment: @Media I don't know what you mean by an affine set; perhaps you mean an [affine subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space).  In any case, the feasible set for a convex optimization problem is a convex set and conversely any convex set can be the feasible set to a convex optimization problem, so my statement is correct.